# WCF 3.5 adding IErrorHandler does not get called

Tags: wcf, http, rest

I'm configuring a REST WCF service via code, and something is not right. I create an error handler with the code as below.

When I run our service, (self-hosted), the ProvideFault code is hit when I throw a WebFaultException with a Unauthorized status code. The problem is that the client (a browswer), gets **"The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details."**
Any idea what I'm missing? Also, since I'm self hosting there is no "server logs", so basically I'm completely in the dark. Is there anyway to capture "server logs" in a self hosted service?

NOTE: The WebFaultException is one we wrote since we're using 3.5.

```
public class WebErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    private IErrorHandler m_chainedHandler;

    public WebErrorHandler(IErrorHandler chainedHandler)
    {
        m_chainedHandler = chainedHandler;
    }

    #region IErrorHandler Members

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        return m_chainedHandler.HandleError(error);
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion version, ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message fault)
    {
        WebFaultException ex = error as WebFaultException;
        if (ex != null)
        {
            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, "");
            HttpResponseMessageProperty p = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();
            p.StatusCode = ex.Status;
            p.StatusDescription = "Another test";

            fault.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, p);
        }
        else
        {
            m_chainedHandler.ProvideFault(error, version, ref fault);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually handle the error you should return true from handle error. Calling the nested handlers may cause the error to be thrown. (And if the chained handler is null the chained call will cause an NullReferenceException).

Comment: I changed the code in HandleError to return true with no change in the result. I thought HandleError gets called afterwards anyway. In anycase, it seems like the service is ignoring the fault I'm creating in the handler.